# Internet doesn't work on my android emulator?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, internet-connection

I'm developing a flutter app, I'm using Intelji as my IDE and Pixel_2_API_28 as my emulator, Everything working perfectly 2 days before and My internet connection is perfect and fast, I did not change anything in my connectivity or nothing else. What went wrong here?  [image]

Comment: I have had this happen to me too. I also would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try a different virtual device?

Comment: **It's working perfectly while I using a different emulator**, Thank you, What do you think ? What went wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

> Please Check PC Network, If PC Network Are Working Fine, Then Check
>   Emulator WiFi and Data Connection.
>
> If Emulator WiFi & Data Connection (Internet) are off, please turn on
>   both and check again.
>
> It's Work for me.

Comment: try to wipe data

Answer (score -1):

You can just use your real device to test and It will be better.

1. Just connect your mobile with usb to your computer.
2. turn on USB debugging in developer mode.
3. you will see a dialog box in mobile just allow and you are ready to use it.

Hope it will be helpful I suggest it coz once when I was trying my app in emulator it was working fine but when I have tested it on real device many things were not working and I have to start my project from scratch. So I suggest to test on real device.